# I'm trying to create a dot chart using a matplot function. X becomes a variable and Y is a quantity. The order is reversed

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a dot chart, but there is a bug in my code.  I don't see the error.

```
data1<-cbind(c(1,3,5),c(10,2,3))
dim(data1)

matplot(data1,1:3,pch=20,xlim=c(0,1),yaxt="n", xaxt="n", 
        xlab = "Number of trees by ratio", ylab ="Tree type", 
        ylim = c(1,3), main="Tree concentrations in MI",col="blue","green")
```

Comment: `col` should be `col=c("blue","green")`.

Comment: Change `xlim` to `c(0, 10)` to include all points of  `data1` if that is required